# Unhandled Promise Rejection in Script

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a functioning script (see below) that correctly scrapes the data of Argentina's Supreme Court decisions based on the thematic issue ("voces", in Spanish) and saves it as a json file. I wrote it with the amazing help of [this community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492290/pagination-when-there-is-no-next-page-button-but-bunch-of-page-numbers-pages). However, when trying to change just a little bit of the script to get cases between a time period (e.g., since 1/1/2020) I get an Unhandled Promise Rejection

I am trying to change the lines that input the information and get the list of results.

```
// wait until element ready  
    await Promise.all([
        page.type('#fechaDesde', '01/01/2020')
    ]);

    await Promise.all([
    page.click('.glyphicon-search'),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
  ]);
```

It works, but the process gets stuck in the first page and fails to paginate. I can't imagine that is a problem in the function, for it works so well in the other script (see below). Any ideas?

**Full script that works** ->

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://sjconsulta.csjn.gov.ar/sjconsulta/');

  // wait until element ready  
    await Promise.all([
        page.type('#voces', 'DERECHO DE ACCESO A LA INFORMACION PUBLICA'),
        page.waitForSelector('.ui-menu-item')
    ]);

    await page.click('.ui-menu-item');

    await Promise.all([
    page.click('.glyphicon-search'),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
  ]);

    var results = []; // variable to hold the "sumarios" I need
    var lastPageNumber = 5; // I am using 2 to test, but I can choose any number and it works (in this case, the 31 pages I need to scrap)
    for (let index = 0; index < lastPageNumber; index++) {
        // wait 1 sec for page load
        await page.waitFor(5000);
        // call and wait extractedEvaluateCall and concatenate results every iteration.
        // You can use results.push, but will get collection of collections at the end of iteration
        results = results.concat(await getSumarios(page)); // I call my function but the function does not work, see below 
        if (index != lastPageNumber - 1) {
            await page.click('li.paginate_button.active + li a[onclick]'); //This does the trick 
            await page.waitFor(5000);
            console.log("...")
        }
    }

    browser.close();
    return results;

};

    async function getSumarios(page) {
    
    const result = await page.evaluate ( () => {

        let data = [];
        //let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9 datosSumario"]'), element => element.textContent);
        let divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('div[class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9 datosSumario"]')];
        
        //Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9 datosSumario"]'), element => element.textContent)

        for (var element in divs){
    
        let title = document.querySelector('div[class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9 datosSumario"]').innerText;
        let numero = document.querySelector('div[class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-3 numero"]').innerText;
        let date = document.querySelector('div[class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-2 numero"]').innerText;
        let fallos = document.querySelector('div[class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2 numero"]').innerText;
        let reporter = "Fallos"; // Para ya tener a "Fallos" en el dataset

        var fallos2 = fallos.substring(8); //remove "Fallos: "

        var title2 = title.split('\n')[0]; // eliminamos lo que sobra del título
        
        var array = fallos2.split(':'),
            volume = array[0], page = array[1];

        data.push({title2,numero,date,reporter,volume,page,fallos2});

        }

        return data;

    });

    

    return result

    await page.click('div[clas=col-sm-4 col-lg-3 > btn btn-default]');


    
    };

scrape().then((results) => {
    console.log(results); // Success!
    let data = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync('voces_aip.json', data);
    
});
```

Comment: somewhere you're getting a rejection - but you're not handling rejections - either use `.catch` on a Promise ... or use try/catch when using `await` to handle rejections

Comment: note: `await page.click('div[clas=col-sm-4 col-lg-3 > btn btn-default]');` is unreachable since you `return result` in the line before that

Comment: though `'div[clas=col-sm-4 col-lg-3 > btn btn-default]'` is not a valid selector anyway